# How to access cookie values on different paths of the same domain using PHP?

Tags: php, cookies

Can a parameter of path be added to $_COOKIE[]?

Comment: You might find [`$cookie->setPath($path)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Cookie/blob/004cde69ec840e65c15275e09b92ecb1da06f357/src/Cookie.php#L104) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Cookie).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In case you are trying to access cookies set for a different path on the same domain than the current, that can't be done. The browser itself restricts this, and only sends the cookies appropriate for the current path.

Comment: what about facebook?, facebook writes cookies for the domain "facebook.com", but it uses this cookies from "www.facebook.com"

Comment: @user962284 are you sure? I'm pretty sure FB sets all cookies on www.facebook.com, as it's not even possible to access facebook.com (they redirect you to www.)

Comment: This is incorrect. A browser following the recommendations of the RFC *does* send both values back in the case of more than one cookie with the same name but different paths. It is in fact PHP that gets in the way; please see my posted answer.

Answer (score 5):

While the HTTP client (ie: browser) does not send back the path that the cookie was set to, PHP actually makes assumptions about cookies with regards to its *$_COOKIE* array.

If you set two cookies with the same name, one with the value "first-value" with path */* and the second with the value "second-value" with path */test*, a browser following the recommended - but not required - behaviour from the RFC will send back both values to you. When you access a URL under the */test* path, the browser sends this:

```
Cookie: name=second-value, name=first-value
```

The "problem" is that PHP only reads the first value - *$_COOKIE['name']* will only contain the value "second-value" with no hint that "first-value" exists. If you need access to both values, you need to parse the value of *$_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']* yourself - this will contain "name=second-value, name=first-value" for the above example. Note that "second-value" is first in line because it was set with a longer path. Please note that the RFC does not guarantee this behaviour, it only says that HTTP clients *SHOULD* do this.

Comment: Interesting, is this specific to subdirectories? As in, a request to a subdirectory will receive the root's cookies, but a request to the root will not receive cookies for subdirectories? Also I'm curious to whether browsers actually implement this or not :)

Comment: Correct, a subdirectory or longer path will always receive a cookie with a shorter path that matches. All browsers are implemented this way. The only thing that is not guaranteed behaviour is if you have multiple cookies with the same name but different paths - you *should* receive both cookies back in a fixed order, but the RFC does not make any promises.

Comment: This is actually the correct answer since it gives a full explanation as to why this happens. I should note, and this is missing, though you cannot tell `$_COOKIE[]` a path, you can tell `setcookie` a path. We are facing this with an API. So you can actually tell `setcookie` to set the root path then access it anywhere, like so: `setcookie('name', 'data', expire, '/')`. That last parameter is the path and setting it to `/` makes it root path. This would solve the OP's problem.

Comment: Building on what Nate had mentioned about the cookies being available via $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']... use this to place the individual cookies into an array:

`$cookies = parse_ini_string( str_replace( ";" , "\n" , $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'] ) ) ;`

Answer (score 2):

yes, it's the 4th argument, but you will only be able to access the cookie if it was set using a path that the current directory resides in.

that's confusing... here it is from php:

> The path on the server in which the
>   cookie will be available on. If set to
>   '/', the cookie will be available
>   within the entire domain . If set to
>   '/foo/', the cookie will only be
>   available within the /foo/ directory
>   and all sub-directories such as
>   /foo/bar/ of domain . The default
>   value is the current directory that
>   the cookie is being set in.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

You access it like any other cookie. It will become available in $_COOKIE if the script has access to it.

Comment: I mean how to read it, how to access cookie values in different paths but on the same domain name?

Comment: php doesn't do that for you. you would have to implement that yourself.

Answer (score 2):

No, such parameters are impossible because the browser does not send the path to the server. It does only send the name and the value of each cookie (so you can't see the path, if it's a session cookie, when it will expires and so on).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it will be possible to get the cookie from a different path, since it could possibly cause a security issue.