# Use same session with two tomcat applications

Tags: java, session, tomcat, gwt, tomcat7

I have two applications located on the same tomcat7 server:

1. https://my.application.com/writeApplication
2. https://my.application.com/readApplication

Now what I want to achive is that the *writeApplication* writes something into the session, afterwards the *readApplication* gets started and reads this information out of the session.

In both web.xml files I inserted:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>720</session-timeout>
    <cookie-config>
        <name>JSESSIONID</name>
        <path>/</path>
        <http-only>true</http-only>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

In the *writeApplication* (a simple servlet) I write into the session like:

```
HttpSession session = req.getSession();
session.setAttribute("test", "myString");
```

Like wished the `JSESSIONID`-Cookie is written to `"/"` so https://my.application.com/.

In my *readApplication* (a GWT application) I want to read this information out of the session by using:

```
HttpSession httpSession = getThreadLocalRequest().getSession();
String myString = (String) httpSession.getAttribute("test");
```

In this case I always receive `null`.

If I write something by the *readApplication* the path is the same like in the *writeApplication*, but if I want to read I can't get the information I was adding with the servlet.

Shouldn't it work like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This generally cannot be done, as [this SO question discusses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256164/java-how-to-share-the-session-between-two-or-more-web-application).

However, one common alternative to using the session, which is even viewed as being preferable to using the session, is writing to a database.  It *is* generally possible for two different Java web applications to share the same database, even the same table.  You could have your two webapps write and read shared state from a common database.

Comment: My hope was to avoid this. In this case I would have to give a parameter with the id of the db entry within the url. How could I be sure that only the one who called the *writeApplication* is able to read this information out of the db.

Comment: @mxlse Playing the devil's advocate, how could Tomcat (or JBoss, etc.) manage the same, if a session is to be shared across two web applications?

Comment: Alright , thank you. I think I will solve it with an own cookie in my implementation.