# Jquery Cookie Path Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am using Jquery Cookie and I am trying to retrieve a cookie in a different directory that I set like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#saveForm").click(function () {
     $.cookie('myCookie', $("#Website").val(), {
    expires: 365,
    path: '/'
         });
     });
</script>
```

The cookie is stored, I verified it in my browser's cookies. So I am trying to retreive it with this, but its not getting it. Is there something wrong with the path or is my code wrong?

This is the code I am using to try to retrieve it with:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Website").val($.cookie('myCookie'));
    path: '/'
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible to read cookie from a different path

Comment: What's that `path: '/'` doing there, outside an object literal? Anyway, you don't need to specify the path when reading a cookie, only when setting it.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967963/how-to-access-cookie-values-on-different-paths-of-the-same-domain-using-php

Comment: if you want to allow anybody from the same domain to read the cookie just leave the path setting

Comment: You can access a cookie if the path is a parent of your current path.

Comment: @barmar I only tried to use the path because it is only working on the pages in the directory I set the cookie in. So I tried to add the path

Comment: But you didn't even add it as an argument to `$.cookie`, it's just sitting in your function doing nothing.

Comment: @ArunPJohny I used the code you gave me the other day and it worked at setting it and retrieving it on pages in the same directory, but when I tried to retrieve it on a page outside of the directory it did not work, so that is why I am trying a path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure but your code has some typos:

[$.cookie Reference here](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie#usage)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () { //<-------------no end tag of this
    $("#saveForm").click(function () {
     $.cookie('myCookie', $("#Website").val(), {
    expires: 365,
    path: '/'
         }); //<---end of $.cookie
     }); //<----end of .click
</script>
```

so this should be like this:

```
 <script>
      $(document).ready(function () { 
         $("#saveForm").click(function () {
            $.cookie('myCookie', $("#Website").val(), {
                expires: 365,
                path: '/'
            }); //<---end of $.cookie
          }); //<----end of .click
      }); //<----end of doc ready
</script>
```

and with reading cookies you have to do just this as you mentioned the global cookie:

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#Website").val($.cookie('myCookie'));
      });
</script>
```

So the final code should be:

```
 <script>
      $(document).ready(function () { 
         $("#saveForm").click(function () {
            $.cookie('myCookie', $("#Website").val(), {
                expires: 365,
                path: '/'
            }); //<---end of $.cookie
          }); //<----end of .click

         $("#Website").val($.cookie('myCookie'));

      }); //<----end of doc ready
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks I am going to try it now

Comment: Thanks for the cleaning the code up. The only thing is that was not the problem. The problem I was asking for help with is when I try to retrieve the cookie from a different directory, it does not find it. I have no problems getting it when it is in the same directory

Answer (score 0):

The path is not referring to a directory that the cookie is stored in, it's referring to what url the cookie is valid and available for