# Retrieving all subdomaines/superdomains cookies from with subdomain using javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am getting partial list of cookies with `document.cookie` when executing on subdomain. I would like to retrieve superdomain+subdomain cookies. Is there any way to do that?

Let say I have a domain

- example.com
- sub.example.com

And I have cookies set

name=value   domain

- c1=2     =>   .example.com
- c2=4     =>   sub.example.com

If url in browser is sub.example.com I want to get all the above cookies how would I do that? `document.cookie` only returns c2=4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a flag in browser which sets `httponly` cookie, This cookie is not visible from `document.cookie` javascript method for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access cookies from different domain. Browser not going to allow this. Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967963/how-to-access-cookie-values-on-different-paths-of-the-same-domain-using-php).

Comment: Can access subdomain cookies if cookie domain is prepended with a period(.) RFC reference https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2109