# php sessions doesn't continue previous sessions when set over specific pathes

Tags: php, session, cookies

my objective:
I set two cookies over two different pathes containing session Ids

These two pathes are not common so cookies are not shared
`/baharshop/admin/`
`/baharshop/public/` 
in requests from `/baharshop/admin/` only one session is created but in requests from `/baharshop/public/`  sessions keep creating and can't get a hold to previous session
and also if I write session_start in `/baharshop/public/`  and only run requests from `/baharshop/admin/` again new sessions are created for `/baharshop/public/`  without even runnig any requests from `/baharshop/public/`

now my project directory design is like this

1. /baharshop/ -- root director
2. /baharshop/admin/
3. /baharshop/public/

upon loading any requests from `/baharshop/admin/` I first include file `config_admin.php` to start one session only

```
config_admin.php

session_set_cookie_params((7 * (24*3600)), "/baharshop/admin/");
session_start();
```

then offcourse include the file in all `/baharshop/admin/` applications

```
<?php require_once "../config/config_admin.php";?>
<?php
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_COOKIE);
echo "</pre>";

}
?>
```

and it works just fine

problem is upon only adding these lines in `config_public.php`

```
config_public.php 
session_set_cookie_params( ((6*31) * (24*3600)), "/baharshop/public/");
session_start();
```

then for every request from `"/baharshop/public/"` new sessions keep creating again and again

```
<?php require_once "../config/config_public.php";?>

<?php

function get_content(): void{
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_COOKIE);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: _"I create a file on server save it in cookie"_ - uhm, where? I do not see you explicitly setting an individual cookie containing that kind of information anywhere in what you have shown us so far. All I see you do, is mess with the _session_ cookie settings.

Comment: @CBroe in config/config_admin.php ``` session_set_cookie_params(DAYS_TO_KEEP_SESSION_FILE_ADMIN_SESS_ID_IN_BROWSER_COOKIE, SESSION_SET_COOKIE_PARAMS_ADMIN_PATH);
session_start();``` shouldn't these two lines create session and store session in cookie? check out github file

Comment: _"check out github file"_ - no, check out [ask] and [mre] - whatever information is necessary for us to be able to reproduce your problem, belongs directly into your question.

Comment: _"shouldn't these two lines create session and store session in cookie?"_ - they should set session cookie parameters, and then start the session, yes. But what does that have to do with what you said you are doing - storing a file name into a cookie? (You are aware that the session _data_ is not actually stored _in_ the cookie, right?)

Comment: @CBroe sorry for the misinformation. I edited question and added all the code needed.
"storing a file name into a cookie?" "You are aware that the session data is not actually stored in the cookie, right?)" I wanted to say only session file name is stored in cookie under PHPSESSID KEY. I mean when a session is started a file is created on server. The name of the file is stores in cookie not the data.

Comment: _"and added all the code needed"_ - or, probably, much more than that. Sorry, but you are not supposed to just dump _everything_ here - but reduce it to the relevant parts. And a proper explanation of what you are even trying to _achieve_ here in the first place, would also not go amiss.

Comment: @CBroe I appreciate your answers. I just moved relevant parts to end of the section. let me know if you need more information. and really thank you

Comment: Still not sure what exactly you are even trying to achieve here in the first place. Can't tell right now, whether the session would be the best place to store the info you need. What if your admin users explicitly log out of their session? Then you can set the cookie lifetime to seven days all you want ...

Comment: @CBroe Lets say i simply want a cookie for admin folder, and another cookie for public folder, now these cookies must contain sessionid. Now public cookie value keeps changing which means new session in created each time so i cant keep customer logged in. And i store admin name and customer name in session

Comment: Let's stop using the terms "cookie" and "session" as if they were one any the same thing, first of all. If you want a separate session for your admin area - then you should (also) specify a different session _name_ for that, that is probably the easiest way to avoid cookie _path_ trouble.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for your creative answer. How should i do that? I read something about session_regenare_id but couldnt get it to work

Comment: ID != name. session_regenerate_id is for cases in which you want to keep all the data in your current session, and only want to generate a new session ID at some point (for security or other reasons.) https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php

Answer (score 0):

The basics of a session in PHP:

**session_name**

- The name of the session (not to be confused with the *session*_**id** !!!). It normally is PHPSESSID, but you can change it to something like SOMENAME if you want.
- If you use sessions, all users of your site will have a cookie with this **name**, but all the cookies will have a different **value**, namely the...

**session_id**

- A random id generated by PHP, for example: `abcde12345`
- A _session **file** with the same name (`sess_abcde12345`) is created in de session storage folder on the server.
- As the PHP script ends, the *session*_**id** is forgotten, but the *session* **file** still exists.
- To know the name of the *session* **file** to use for a particular user, there is the...

**session_cookie**

- a cookie in the browser, where the *session*_**id** is stored (only the id, no other data!).
- the *session*_**name** is the **NAME** of the cookie.
- the *session*_**id** is the **VALUE** of the cookie.
- It is send to the server with every request and can be read by PHP so it can use the correct *session* **file**.

**session_file**

- The file stored on the server by PHP, containing the data.
- It can be accessed (after calling `session_start()`) by using `$_SESSION[ somekey]`.
- If the browser is closed, the *session*_**cookie** is deleted and the connection between user and the session file on the server is forever lost, unless you change the lifetime of the cookie. But I won't recommend that. It's called a *session* so use it for the period the user has your site open. Important data should be stored in a database or different folder and file, as the session file can deleted.

Now to your question: why use **TWO** different sessions for admin and user? **ONE** would do, as the session data is basically an array and can contain anything, and the session is - if you don't change settings - valid for the entire domain.

If the user logs in set `$_SESSION['user_id']=userID`. Every subsequent call to the server to request a user page or user data you can check `if(!empty($_SESSION['user_id']))`. If this is `true` the user is logged in.

The same goes for the admin pages. If the admin logs in, set `$_SESSION['admin_id']=adminID` and check in subsequent admin pages. (Instead of adminID you can also use the userID, as long as you use different **array keys** to check for: user_id for user pages and admin_id for admin pages.)

This can all be done by the same session, even in different tabs in your browser.

You can even differentiate between users with no admin rights and users with admin rights when they login as normal user. Simply set something like `$_SESSION['IsAlsoAdmin']=true`. In that case, the user can go from user pages directly to admin pages, without having to login again (and vice versa).

All that said, if you really, really want to use two different sessions, you have to change the path of the session cookie by using [`session_set_cookie_params`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php). There, in the `path` part of the command, you have to differentiate to make the session cookie only valid for the admin part of your domain. But read [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24226102/1685196) about the pitfalls of that approach.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem using your solution which is using only one session for root and all subdirectories 
The answer you attached was also very helpful But it was also for the case of root cookie being shared with subdirectories. in my case they are two different pathes.I saved one cookie in``` /baharshop/admin/ ``` and the other in ```/baharshop/public/``` so althoght cookies name are the same PHPSESSID but they are not shared. So the question still remains that why php engine keeps creating new sessions when accessing /baharshop/public/ directory and subdirectories